# Handling CORS from a thirdparty API

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I'm a bit new to react and I am trying to fetch Crypto data from the Nomics API. I read their documentations and used axios for my GET request like so:

```js
fetchChartData(currency, start) {
    const data = {
      key: "key",
      currency: currency,
      start: start
    }

    return axios({
      method: "get",
      url: API_URL + '/exchange-rates/history',
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        crossorigin: true
      },
      data
    })
  }
```

For which I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource.
```

So I decided to use `Moesif Origin and CORS changer`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.nomics.com/v1/exchange-rates/history' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I don't know why it is being blocked because it says "localhost requests are always allowed to ease development" in the documentation.

[![Nomics docs on CORS][1]][1]

My other attempts of fixing this are adding stuff to the headers and proxy.
My proxy went like this, (never proxy-ed before):

```js
const API_URL = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.nomics.com/v1`

fetchChartData(currency, start) {
    const key = "key";

    return axios({
      method: "get",
      url: API_URL +
        '/exchange-rates/history?' +
        `?key=${key}
          &currency=${currency}
          &start=${start}` 
    })
  }
```

With proxy, however, I just get a 401 (Unauthorized).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIT7L.png

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

The problem is that the domain you're using does not match the domain that the API is expecting for development. A domain is identified for CORS purposes (also known as the *Same Origin Policy*) based on three parts: *protocol*, *host*, and *port*. Using the following domain: *https://example.com*, I'll explain these three parts below:

1. **Protocol** - *http* or *https* depending on if security is enabled on the domain. For our example it would be *https*.
2. **Host** - for the example above this would be *example.com*.
3. **Port** - The default ports are typically: 80 for *http* and 443 for *https*. In our example, our port is 443.

It's important to know the information above so that you can identify the problem in your code snippet. The documentation notes that `localhost` is always supported for development. However, your domain `http://localhost:3000` does not match the documentation because the ports are different.

**The Fix**

You'll need to run your application locally at `http://localhost` (default port 80) for the API call to succeed and pass the CORS preflight test. I don't see it noted above, but if the documentation requires a secure `localhost` environment then you'd want to run your application locally at `https://localhost` (default port 443). In addition, you'd probably have to create a self-signed SSL certificate for this to work properly.

Comment: I suspected something like that, but I disregarded it cause I thought 3000 was the default port. Lemme give that a shot.

Comment: How do I set React to port 80, right now it's on port :1 . I tried to use `    "start": "set PORT=80 && react-scripts start"` in my package.json.